# CTW AspectJ classes can't use @Autowiring in Spring Web

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

How do I get CTW classes to properly `@Autowired` in Spring Web applications?

I've seen some odd runtime behavior wrt `aspectJ woven` classes, both LTW and CTW.  Both LTW and CTW manifest with the same odd symptoms as noted below.  They "seemed" to go away for LTW after I bumped the JVM's heap, but I can't seem to reach a solution for CTW, which I'd prefer.

I created a Spring forum thread and got zero traction: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/725024-cached-ltw-classes-aren-t-getting-autowired

The critical issue here is this: nested exception is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com//application/thread/MyApplicationJob$AjcClosure3.
```

This is a maven project, and my aspects are in a different project's module.  This a brief accounting of my maven's pom:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.3</org.aspectj-version>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <wendelnet-version>2.3</wendelnet-version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>

                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <complianceLevel>${java-version}</complianceLevel>

                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.wendelnet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>


            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.wendelnet</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${wendelnet-version}</version>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The project compiles fine, and the methods I'd expect to get woven are, in fact, woven as noted via `showWeaveInfo`.
Using Spring 3.0.5.